# memory management in python while running large calculations

Tags: python, memory-management, mathematical-optimization

i want to run a simple program with large integers.
Program is to calculate "Perfect Number"

```
def is_perfect(x):
    sum_of_positive_divisors = 0
    for i in range(1,(x//2)+1):
        if x%i == 0:
            sum_of_positive_divisors+=i
    if x == sum_of_positive_divisors:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for n in range(1,32):
    print("n is %s",n)
    num = 2**(n-1)*((2**n)-1)
    if is_perfect(num):
        print(num)
```

when i run this program in jupyter notebook. Its runs for long time with NO peak in memory.

but when i run it on command prompt. I get memory error in 10 seconds.

I am running on Python 3.8 on Raspberry Pi 4 (8gb)

please help !!

Comment: If I followed the code correctly you are running about 2**60 iterations. Independent of the memory problem you shouldn't have other plans for the RPi in the next few years.

Comment: Thank you so much Klaus. for bringing out my pain point. 
I am looking for algorithm optimisation

If i can get some pointers

Comment: I was able to optimize little further. 

added function to find if (2^n)-1 is *prime* then (2^(n-1))*((2^n)-1) is perfect. 

I am able to calculate  upto n equal to 89 (in less than hour)... and continuing now.